# Input fields won't allow some operators to be printed

Tags: php

I have an input form which I use in order to post some data in the database, the issue is it won't allow me to post characters like "+", "&" etc..

Now I've used this format:

```
$postPagesashtepi = $_POST["postPagesashtepi"];
```

The form looks like this:

```
<input id="pagesashtepi" name="pagesashtepi" type="text" size="40" value="<?php echo $row['pagesashtepi'];?>
```

I've also used `filter sanitized` too but no success again..
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Show the code you use to insert the data into the database.

Comment: You're new to HTTP, aren't you.

Comment: You Form Method is Post?

Comment: try to echo your posted variable and see whether the data is there or not...

Comment: Yes , well, the data doesn't go in the database though...
i mean, i can't seem to write this operators in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use

```
 $string=stripslashes($string);
```

This make your input Un-quotes for DB

use This Function For Safe input

```
function dbcodec($string){
    $string=stripslashes($string);
    $string=str_replace("\\",'\\',$string);
    $string=str_replace("'","\'",$string);
    $string=str_replace("`","\`",$string);
    $string=str_replace('"','\"',$string);
    $string=str_replace('*','\*',$string);
    return $string;
}
```

and You Can Use **mysql_real_escape_string** for escape input

Comment: @pyetjegoo test This .What is The SQL Error?; and **print_r($_POST);** to see is any post input

Comment: @pyetjegoo and You Can Use **mysql_real_escape_string** for escape input

Comment: Thanks for trying mohammad, but my issue is i am using odbc connection so.. it wouldn;t work..

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are outputting user-supplied content to the browser, you should always call [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) on it to make sure people don't inject HTML into your pages.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work..
if i insert characters like "&" it won't work at all, it's like it doesn't accept the input..
i'm using php and SQL server.. i guess , i read it might have something to do with utf encode..something..

Answer (score 0):

You passed wrong name in post.

`$postPagesashtepi = htmlspecialchars($_POST["postPagesashtepi"]);`

Comment: No, because i post it with ajax so the name is not correct..but using htmlspecialchars won't post too...

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work..
if i insert characters like "&" it won't work at all, it's like it doesn't accept the input..
i'm using php and SQL server.. i guess , i read it might have something to do with utf encode..something..